# Texture and cutting of avocado and Mango used in sushi

Tags: sushi

When I want to make sushi, how should the avocado and mango feels like ? Soft or very soft ?

Plus how should I cut the mango to put on the top of sushi ? I searched on youtube but nothing helped me their.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avocado: Soft, but not too soft.
Mango, a little bit under ripe.

So, it is always to your own taste.

As to how to cut the mango, I would cut in half and make thin sliced (a little bit like cutting fish for sushi).

Video showing how to cut a mango (like a pro) for sushi rolls.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL6J_hy3sHM

Comment: I need picture/video about it. I can't figure it how.

Comment: most videos show how to make cubes after removing the pit; instead of cutting in cube, just make thin slices; it's not that difficult.
anyway, here you go : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL6J_hy3sHM

Comment: Not sure if that video is actually the easiest way to cut thin even slices. I know you can do it if you're good with the knife, but it's probably easier to cut them vertically. That is, take one of the halves (flat on one side, round on the other), put it with the flat side down, and cut thin vertical slices.

Comment: I know, but it is the closest I could find while being at work; most video show mangos being cut in cubes or thick slices.